# Regex Expressions

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to learn to handle Regex Expressions and got some exercises but no solutions to it. One Question is: all lower-case words except 'if'.

Can I do this one like this:

```
[a-z][a-z]^[if] | [a-z][a-z][a-z]+
```

I'm expect that a word has at least two characters. So every word with three or more is okay.

Comment: post some examples.. Did you want to match `fooifbar`?

Comment: if you are experimenting, then try [regetron](https://gitorious.org/regetron)

Comment: "At least two" should also include two. Be careful with your spaces around the `|`, those are included in pattern matching. www.regex101.com is a good experimental site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... the full *real* solution would be something like that:

```
\b(?!if\b)\p{Ll}+\b
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qL4fK7/1)

But I suppose it's, well, "higher level" regex that you didn't learn yet.

So, let's keep things simple. If you can accept to ignore words of less than 3 characters, you can write this:

```
\b[a-hj-z][a-eg-z][a-z]+|i[a-z]{2,}
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bI6cG1/2)

The first two character classes are just `[a-z]` without `i` and `f` respectively.

If you want to include words of less than 3 characters, this will do:

```
\b(?:i|if[a-z]+|i[a-eg-z][a-z]*|[a-hj-z][a-z]*)\b
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qL4fK7/4)

But it gets complicated at this point...

Comment: your first regex would match a single character.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes , that was the point, I was trying to relax the 3+ letter requirement. After all "a" is still a word.

Answer (score 1):

All sequences of two or more lower-case letters, except "if":

```regexp
[a-hj-z][a-z]+|i(?:[a-eg-z][a-z]*|f[a-z]+)
```

With negative look-ahead, you can also do:

```regexp
(?!if\b)[a-z]{2,}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to place what you want to ignore on the left side of the alternation operator and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right side of the alternation operator as you were attempting.

```
\bif\b|([a-z]{2,})
```

**Note:** The caret `^` outside of a character class does not mean negation, it asserts the position at start of the string. And unless you are using the `x` (free-spacing) modifier, you need to remove the spaces between the alternation.